# Interactable and invisible TextField in FlashPunk

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently working on a game in ActionScript 3 (using FlashPunk) and due to FP's limitation in handling input (~, ^, ã and so on) I ended up having to use AS 3's native TextField class. Through that I capture text, send it to one of my entities in FlashPunk and have it render the text as a graphic (for a text balloon).

My question is: is there a way to make the TextField object invisible yet still interactable?What I want to do is: make the TextField object have focus without the user having to click on it (and it cannot appear on the screen, nor its text, but it must capture the typed text). Is it do-able through sheer code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer will be different depending on the platform target. What platform are this for?

Comment: Browser application, currently testing with FireFox, for some reason I couldn't run it on Chrome. Using FlashBuilder 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via `stage.focus = textFieldInstance;` ([adobe reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#focus)). As for making it invisible...

All sorts of tricks are available for this

- moving the textfield off screen
- hiding the textfield behind something else
- `textfield.width = 0`
- `setTextFormat` with a font that has a size of 0...

There is, of course, also `textField.visible = false`, but there's a lot of things associated with that that will break what we're trying to achieve.

Whilst googling I found some cases of people having trouble with just using `stage.focus` however, so if that doesn't work, try this ([original source](http://reality-sucks.blogspot.nl/2007/11/actionscript-3-adventures-setting-focus.html)):

```
myTF.type="input";
myTF.text=" "; //a SPACE or temp "foo" text, but NOT empty !
myTF.stage.focus = myTF; 
myTF.setSelection(myTF.length,myTF.length);
myTF.text = "";
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, hadn't actually thought about that (reducing width or toying with the font).

I did try stage.focus(myTextField), though it didn't work at the time, I recall I getting an exception, guess I'll look into it, thanks! :)

Comment: added adobe's language reference of `stage.focus` to the post, hope that it helps.

Comment: Well, I worked with this and ended up having the focus work. It now returns the focus to the text field after the message is sent or the mouse is clicked elsewhere. However, I can't for the life of me have the text field gain focus as soon as the program launches. 

I've made it gain focus on every update but it takes at least one click somewhere else for it to work. I know it's not such a great pain but it'd be a nice thing to have it start focused. The previous answer was tremendously helpful by the way (it seems the focus works even if the text is empty [""]).

Comment: I realized it might not had been gaining focus since the beginning due to the application not being focused on the browser, as soon as I click the screen the magic happens and it works as it should ;P.